# ASP.NET Add-Migration No DbContext was found in assembly

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

The first time I started working my add-migration command didn't work, after that I installed the latest version of entity-framewrok and it worked. When I shut down the project and started the day tomorrow, it didn't work for me again.

[image]

Comment: Please always paste errors as text, not as image

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple projects please compile first, also you can remove the multiple project run settings. Try to select one project (for example you can select your api project). Make sure you have your constructor method is set up properly.

For example:

```
 public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }
```

And if you are using different environment settings like development, staging or production, you can move the AddDbContext behaviour out of the if-else statement.

For example:

```
else if(_env.IsStaging() || _env.IsProduction())
{
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>{
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    });
}
```

Before adding migrations, I move AddDbContext section out of the if block. You can also define the environment on Package Manager Console like:

$ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Staging"

If you check your Properties -> launchSettings.json you can see:

```
 "WebAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      //"launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging" //here
      }
    }
```

If everything fails, go back to first rule of being I.T.

1. Close IDE
2. Delete .vs folder
3. Compile your project
4. Be sure Default Project is set up properly on Package Manager Console(the project which has your database Context)
5. Add migrations